# I'm having issues with my PHP script that sends info submitted from html form

Tags: php, html, mysql

so i'm writing this script to make uploading into my table significantly quicker. I'm not quite sure what's wrong but no matter what I do, I get a "query failed" echo rather than having the content get to the table. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
session_start();

$singer_name = ($_POST['singer_name']);
$song_name = ($_POST['song_name']);
$ctg_name = ($_POST['ctg_name']);
$mp3 = ($_POST['mp3']);
$album_cover = ($_POST['album_cover']);
$link = mysqli_connect("example.com", "user", "pass", "example");
$sql = "INSERT INTO song (singer_name, song_name, ctg_name, mp3, album_cover) 
VALUES ('$insertsinger_name, $insertsong_name, $insertctg_name, $insertmp3, $insertalbum_cover')";  
    if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
            mysqli_close($link);
                    session_write_close();
                    header("location: songadmin.php");
                    exit();
        } else{
            die("Query Failed");
        }

  ?>
```

Comment: None of the variables you are using in the INSERT statement have been initialized.

Comment: The information you're looking for is in `mysqli_error($link)`

Comment: You have many issues here. You should parameterize your query to take out the SQL injection one.

Comment: You use mysqli instead of PDO we all could just you "downvote", whatever the problem is... and seeing die("") like this and indentation and... well.

Answer (score 0):

Should the insert statement not just be this?

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO song (singer_name, song_name, ctg_name, mp3, album_cover) VALUES ('$singer_name', '$song_name', '$ctg_name', '$mp3', '$album_cover')";
```

Comment: No, it shouldn't.  It *should* be using query parameters on a prepared statement.  Which would have the combined benefit of addressing the SQL injection vulnerability as well as making the problem in this question moot.